# JavaScript variable replace issue

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace some strings and variables but I don`t know how to make it - my code is below:

```
var text = "I was born in $city in country $country "

var city = "New YORK"
var country = "USA"

var regex_variable = /\$\s*(.*?)\s/g;
var variable =[];

while (c = regex_variable.exec(text)) {
  variable.push(c[1]);
}

for (n=0;n<variable.length;n++){
  text = text.replace(regex_variable, "kat");
}

console.log(text)
```

Output from this script is:

```
I was born in katin country kat
```

But the point is to replace the `kat` with the strings from variable `city` and `country`. Please note that in the var text some strings has got `$` character as a prefix - this strings I want to take from the variables (strings in the text will be the same as a names of variables but with prefix `$`).

The correct output should be:

```
I was born in New YORK in country USA
```

Anyone could help me with it?

Comment: You may want to look at [JS template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). `var city = 'New York', country = 'USA', text = \`I was born in ${city} in country ${country}\`;`

Comment: the point is that I need to use the $city becase this is just an example - I will received this string from the file with variables like $city

Comment: @RobM. Nice, but not fully compatible.

Comment: FYI it's "JavaScript", not "java script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to build is a little "templating" system. If you search for that, you will find lots of things.

Here's a real simple example:

```js
var city = "New YORK";
var country = "USA";
var interpolations = {city, country};
var text = "I was born in $city in country $country";

var newString = text.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, (match, val) => interpolations[val]);

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Thank you - this what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it like this:

```
var text = "I was born in $city in country $country ";

var city = "New YORK";
var country = "USA";

text = text.replace("$city", city);
text = text.replace("$country", country);

console.log(text)
```

Comment: It`s a simples way - you are right :D but problem will be when I will have got more than 100 of this variables - to make a replace for each variable :)

Comment: Do you know the order of the variables, for example that $city comes first and $country is the secound and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "I was born in $city in country $country "

var city = "New YORK"
var country = "USA"

var replaceArray = [city,country]; //create an array with your variables

var regex_variable = /\$\s*(.*?)\s/g;
var variable =[];

while (c = regex_variable.exec(text)) {
   variable.push(c[1]);
}

for (n=0;n<variable.length;n++){
  text = text.replace("$"+variable[n], replaceArray[n]);
}

console.log(text);
```

If you know the order of the variables you want to replace, this could be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

var city = "NEW YORK"

var country = "USA"

var text = "I was born in city in country "

var res = text.replace(/city/gi, city);

var res1 = res.replace(/country/gi, country);

document.write(res1);

Comment: This is a fine solution, but it's not scalable to many variable names.